# exact matching does not work for SQ() in Haystack?

Tags: solr, django-haystack, solr4, searchqueryset

I am trying to use `__exact` in my Haystack and SOLR4 backend app, but it does not work for `SQ()` as expected. I am wondering whether `__exact` just works for `SearchQuerySet` class. This is my code:

```
    sqs = super(FacetedSearchForm, self).search() 
    author_sq = SQ()     
    title_sq = SQ() 
    author_sq.add(SQ(author__exact=sqs.query.clean(author)), SQ.OR)       
    title_sq.add(SQ(title__exact=sqs.query.clean(title)), SQ.OR) 
    sqs = sqs.filter(author_sq) 
    sqs = sqs.filter(title_sq)
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to get `__exact` work for `SearchQuery` class?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using it like this:

```
sqs = sqs.filter(SQ(text__exact=criteria) | SQ(entries__exact=criteria) | SQ(attr_content__exact=criteria))
```

sqs is a SearchQuerySet